# PromiseKit For In Loop When Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, promise, promisekit

With `Swift`, I am trying to incorporate promises into my code with `PromiseKit` for the first time and am having difficulty understanding syntactically how to make this work.

My goal is to pipeline requests to `Firebase` for data and execute another method once an appended array is fulfilled with all the returned data. It seems the `promise` is resolved and the final method is run before the array is set with the data. I believe I should be using "when", but admittedly have trouble understanding the documentation.

Abbreviated, relevant code below:

```
getPosts(ids).done {
    runningFinalMethod(self.arr)
}

func getPosts(_ ids: [String]) -> Promise<Void>  {
    return Promise { seal in
        for id in ids {
            db.collection("data").whereField("id", isEqualTo: id).getDocuments(completion: { (dataForId, error) in                
                appendData(dataForId)
            })
        }
        seal.fulfill(())
    }
}

func appendData(_ dataForId: [data]) {                                  
    arr.append(contentsOf: dataForId)            
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better that you use `thenMap` in cases like these where you are mapping multiple values asynchronously. Here is how you can achieve this

```
func getPosts(_ ids: [String]) -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise.value(ids).thenMap { id in
        Promise<data> { resolver in
            db.collection("data").whereField("id", isEqualTo: id).getDocuments { dataForId, error in
                guard let error = error else { resolver.fulfill(dataForId) }
                resolver.reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
    .done { allDataForIds in
        self.arr = allDataForIds
    }
    .catch { error in
        // handle error
    }
}
```

`thenMap` allows you to map individual values and then process the value with `Promise`. You can then collect all the value using `done` method, which has all the values from each of the collection promises. By the way, `done` method itself returns `Promise<Void>`, you could simply return that at the end.

Comment: Good answer. Totally forget about `thenMap` :)

Comment: I was looking through their unit tests and found it. I didnt know about it earlier :)